# Customize jupyter notebook design (not just styling)

Tags: python, user-interface, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyterhub

Is it possible to customize jupyter notebook front end part (not just css)?
Basically I want to serve my custom html page which has code block for which I want the functionality of a cell as in Jupyter notebook.  I can customize the styling of the page but didn't find any way to change the layout (html).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `custom.js` file (found in the same place as the `custom.css` file you have likely been editing) to load arbitrary Javascript on page load. You can use this to modify the DOM, for example using JQuery. Or, if you intend on more complicated work or distributing your javascript it would probably be best to make an extension (http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extending/frontend_extensions.html)

If I knew specifically what you were trying to do I could try and help give an example, but here is the basic framework on how to write a `custom.js` file:

```
define([
    'base/js/namespace',
    'base/js/events'
], function(Jupyter, events) {
    events.on('app_initialized.NotebookApp', function(){
        //your custom code here
    });
});
```

Comment: Suppose i want to remove the default panel, place the execute button below each cell. How to do this? I want some sort of rest api for which i will send request to execute my code and return result. This way i will load my own html placing the button as I need and call this api to execute my code.

Comment: Suppose i want to remove the default panel, place the execute button below each cell. How to do this? I want some sort of rest api for which i will send request to execute my code and return result. This way i will load my own html placing the button as I need and call this api to execute my code.

Comment: I am just asking what are the files I have consider to modify design like you said one possiblity being custom.js, also in my research kernel_gateway api seems appropriate..thank you.